# Как сделать чтобы if работал в конце , он всегда false у меня

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


int range = 11;
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * range);

int count, i;
int tries = 4;

System.out.println("Твоя задача угадать  число от 0 до 10");
System.out.print("Введите ваше число --> ");


for (i = 0; i < tries; i++) {

    count = scanner.nextInt();

    if (randomNumber == count) {
        System.out.println("Ты угадал это число!: " + randomNumber);

        break;

    } else if (randomNumber < count && i != tries - 1) {
        System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число меньше твоего " + count);


    } else if (randomNumber > count && i != tries - 1) {
        System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число больше твоего " + count);
    }

    if (tries == 0) {
        System.out.println("Вы потратили все 4 попытки");

        System.out.println("Заданное число было " + randomNumber);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: чему равно выражение `tries - 1` ? ... что надо сделать, чтобы переменная `tries` меняла своё значение в цикле?

Comment: А где Вы вообще меняете значение переменной `tries`? Может, лучше после каждой попытки уменьшать его, сам цикл обратить в `while`?

Comment: Я старался сделать чтобы у меня получилось 4 попытки на ввод, если они исчерпались то вывести у вас не получилось , не смог придумать какая должна быть логика в последнем if, думал  сделать сделать доп переменную boolean и если угадали, присваивать ей true.
Уже после цикла проверять, если не угадали, выводить сообщение. Но не знаю как реализовать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int range = 11;
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * range);

        int count, i;
        int tries = 4;

        System.out.println("Твоя задача угадать  число от 0 до 10");
        System.out.print("Введите ваше число --> ");

        // четыре раза запрашиваю ввод
        for (i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
            count = scanner.nextInt();
            attempt(randomNumber, count, i+1, tries);//передаю i+1 так как счёт в for начинается с нуля
            //если эта попытка четвёртая, то проигрыш
            if (i == 3){
                System.out.println("Вы потратили все 4 попытки");
                System.out.println("Заданное число было " + randomNumber);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void attempt(int randomNumber, int count, int remainingTries, int tries){
        remainingTries = tries - remainingTries;//вычисляю оставшиеся попытки
        if (randomNumber == count) {
            System.out.println("Ты угадал это число!: " + randomNumber);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (randomNumber < count) {
            System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число меньше твоего " + count);
            System.out.println("Осталось попыток: " + remainingTries);
        }
        else if (randomNumber > count) {
            System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число больше твоего " + count);
            System.out.println("Осталось попыток: " + remainingTries);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня вопрос  а как сюда добавить чтобы после каждого ввода выводило у вас осталось н-ное количество попыток? Для этого нужен отдельный метод?

Comment: нет, можно доработать код, сделать?

Comment: да , пожалуйста

Comment: не могу разобраться с этим вообще